# How to add custom check message in checkStyle custom check from configuration box

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I am going through adding custom check as eclipse-cs plugin, and stuck with a problem.

I have created the java file with custom check. The check is working, but i can't change the custom check message as the box is not there.

Java file looks like following :

```
package myCheck.checks;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;

public class MethodLimitCheck extends Check {

    private int max = 30;

    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] { TokenTypes.CLASS_DEF, TokenTypes.INTERFACE_DEF };
    }

    public void setMax(int limit) {
        max = limit;
    }

    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast) {
        // find the OBJBLOCK node below the CLASS_DEF/INTERFACE_DEF
        DetailAST objBlock = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.OBJBLOCK);
        // count the number of direct children of the OBJBLOCK
        // that are METHOD_DEFS
        int methodDefs = objBlock.getChildCount(TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF);
        // report error if limit is reached
        if (methodDefs > max) {
            log(ast.getLineNo(), "methodlimit", max);
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration box looks like:

[image]

I can't change the custom message from here. I want the Box to look like this, so I can set custom message from configuration box:

[image]

What changes to make in my code or any file to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the custom message to your *checkstyle.xml*:

```xml
<module name="MethodLimitCheck">
    <property name="max" value="42"/>
    <message key="methodlimit" value="my test message default"/>
</module>
```

Then it will appear in the eclipse-cs dialog. In your check, you can access the custom messages using the `getCustomMessages()` method ([javadoc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html?com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AbstractViolationReporter.html)).

**Update:**
In order to show your custom messages in the eclipse-cs dialog by default without adding the `<message>` element to your *checkstyle.xml*, you must create a *messages.properties* for your custom check [as described here under "Logging Errors"](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html#Logging_errors). Then, in your Eclipse plugin containing the custom check, you add an element to your *checkstyle-metadata.xml*:

```xml
<rule-metadata name="MethodLimit" internal-name="MethodLimitCheck" parent="TreeWalker">
    <alternative-name internal-name="com.foo.bar.MethodLimitCheck"/>
    <description>...</description>
    <!-- property-metadata -->
    <message-key key="methodlimit" />
</rule-metadata>
```

Comment: Can't I make it appear at the first place. I mean if I `remove the check and add again`, then I have to make `change in xml file again`. Is it possible to get the `MessageBox` in eclipse-cs dialouge at the first place?